# jQuery SimpleTree: Add a node programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a new node to an jQuery [SimpleTree](http://news.kg/wp-content/uploads/tree/), but all I seem to be able to get is "sTC.addNode is not a function"...

```
var simpleTreeCollection = $('.simpleTree').simpleTree({
    animate:true,
    drag:false,
    autoclose: false,
    afterClick:function(node){},
    afterDblClick:function(node){},
    beforeMove:function (destination, source, pos){},
    afterMove:function(destination, source, pos){},
    afterAjax:function() {},
    afterContextMenu:function(node){}
});

simpleTreeCollection.addNode('test', 'test');
```

Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong? Is there even the possibility to add a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a look at [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/jsTree/examples/)

Answer (score 2):

hmm tricky one this and I have to say I dont like the plugin as it uses numerics as id's and w3c states "The attribute's value must begin with a letter in the range A-Z or a-z and may be followed by letters......."

However to get you working u need to select one of the nodes first in order to add to it like this

```
    //Select first child node in tree
    $('#2').click();
    //Add new node to selected node
    simpleTreeCollection.get(0).addNode(1,'A New Node')
```

Comment: It's got a nice "drag'n'drop" feature, even though that one needs some work, too (it's too sensitive, especially when right-clicking for context menus)... I don't think that you NEED to use pure numeric IDs... At least I don't have any and it works...

Comment: Hm, doesn't work. I get a "node[0] is undefined" in jquery.simple.tree.js. Maybe that's because I don't use numeric IDs... Guess I'll try yet another tree plugin. *sigh*

Comment: Hi BlaM, FYI the above code works in the firebug console on their demo page.

Answer (score 0):

FYI the above code works in the firebug console on their demo page. On your tree ake sure you use a correct selector to highlight the node

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by editing the addNode funcion. I commented the temp_node.remove(); and added dragNode_destination.after(dragNode_source);

Just like that:

```
        TREE.addNode = function(id, text, callback)
        {
            var temp_node = $('<li><ul><li id="'+id+'"><span>'+text+'</span></li></ul></li>');
            TREE.setTreeNodes(temp_node);
            dragNode_destination = TREE.getSelected();
            dragNode_source = $('.doc-last',temp_node);
            TREE.moveNodeToFolder(dragNode_destination);
//          temp_node.remove();
            dragNode_destination.after(dragNode_source);
            if(typeof(callback) == 'function')
            {
                callback(dragNode_destination, dragNode_source);
            }
        };
```